# onChange event in select input then display the result of the process on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onchange

I have a form with `select` input inside. When the the `option` changed, the form will be processed (with php) and display the result of the process under the `<form>`.
How to do that?

Here is my html form code :

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <form name="group" id="form1" method="post">
      <select name="group" id="group" onChange="something()">
        <?php foreach ($userGroups['data'] as $groups) {
           echo "<option value=\"".$groups['id']."\">".$groups['name']."</option>";
        }?>
      </select>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php //PROCESSING THE FORM
      if ($_POST) {
         $groupId = $_POST['group'];
         $groupmember = $facebook->api('/'.$groupId.'/members');
         $membergroup = $groupmember['data'];
         foreach ($membergroup as $membergroups) {
            $membergroupsname = $membergroups['name'];      
         }
      }
   ?>
    <!---- THE PLACE WHERE $membergroupsname DISPLAYED ------>

</td>
</tr>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. thank you

Comment: sounds `ajax` for help

Comment: what you want to do when onChange event fire

Comment: @Chandresh the select input contain with all of the user's group on facebook. When user change the select option, the member list of the selected group will appear under the select input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tagged with jquery then I suggest using a `jquery post`

```
$.get( "some.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#membergroupsname" ).html( data );
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Try this  Code

**JQuery**

```
function handleSelect(elm){
    window.location = elm.value;
}
```

**PHP**

```
 <form name="group" id="form1" method="post">
          <select name="group" id="group" onChange="handleSelect(this)">
            <?php foreach ($userGroups['data'] as $groups) {
               echo "<option value=\"index.php?groupname=".$groups['id']."\">".$groups['name']."</option>";
            }?>
          </select>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php //PROCESSING THE FORM
          if ($_GET) {
             $groupId = $_GET ['group'];
             $groupmember = $facebook->api('/'.$groupId.'/members');
             $membergroup = $groupmember['data'];
             foreach ($membergroup as $membergroups) {
                $membergroupsname = $membergroups['name'];      
             }
          }
       ?>
</form>
    <!---- THE PLACE WHERE $membergroupsname DISPLAYED ------>
```

Comment: showing an error : Notice: Undefined index: group in C:\xampp2\htdocs\facebookconnect\basic\js\actions.php on line 172.. if I use $_POST, the error no longer appear but when i change the select option, showing error : Object not found

Comment: It simply redirect Url To url of selected value and then retrive groupid from url. try after removing if($_GET) statement

Comment: Still get the same error after removing if($_GET). URL of this page is actions.php?action=fblogin. So i make "actions.php?action=fblogin?groupname=" in option value. Is it right?

Comment: No Replace Your URL As Below "actions.php?action=fblogin&groupname=" in option Value

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `.change`

```
jQuery('#group').change(function() {
var id_group = this.value; 
var memberjson = "fetchmember.php?group="+id_group;

jQuery("#fetchmember").html('<img src="./templates/standard/images/ajax-loader.gif">');


jQuery.getJSON(memberjson,function(data){

jQuery("#fetchmember").empty();

jQuery.each(data, function(i, item) {
jQuery("#fetchmember").append("write your html");
});
});
});
```